# Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4> vs Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>

Tags: eigen

I'm trying to understand the debug output of CodeLLDB in vs-code.
I have two programs doing almost the same thing, but while debugging, I can see the following difference:

The way an Eigen matrix is displayed differs.
In program A, a matrix is shown as

`Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4>`
and in program B a similar matrix is shown as
`Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>`  in the CodeLLDB debugger.

This is after only initializing the matrices (before resizing them to some required number of rows and columns). What do these numbers indicate? (they clearly are not related to the matrix size...)

Comment: Eigen has both statically sized and dynamically sized matrix dimensions. I would think that `-1` signifies a dynamically sized dimension. Or at least some of the `-1`s

Comment: The template is documented [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html). It is `template<typename Scalar_, int Rows_, int Cols_, int Options_, int MaxRows_, int MaxCols_>
class Eigen::Matrix< Scalar_, Rows_, Cols_, Options_, MaxRows_, MaxCols_ >.`

Comment: -1 is indeed Eigen::Dynamic. So the first is a fixed 4x4 matrix (Eigen::Matrix4f). The second is a dynamic matrix (Eigen::MatrixXf). As for the options, I cannot interpret that. The 4 seems odd or at least doesn't match my version. What version of Eigen is that? In any case, it is probably safe to ignore it. If the bit 1 is set, that indicates row-major ordering. Anything else is just alignment and other details

Comment: ok, thanks for the useful hints. It's still strange that those numbers are set immediately after declaration (before calling `resize(numRows, numCols)`. One would assume that the `resize` command would change the number of rows and cols shown in the `<float, ...> part` (also it's weird that it defaults to "4", but this might be due to different Eigen versions). Unfortunately I could not find the exact Eigen versions (it's a Google Mediapipe / Bazel project).

Comment: @mcExchange Those are template parameters of the template class type, a.k.a. compile time constants. Not runtime variables. Resize on the Matrix4f will just check that you resize to 4x4 because the matrix cannot be any other size. The MatrixXf will do an actual resize and put the size in its attributes. The type itself cannot change.

Comment: Well if anyone wants to make an answer out of the comments, pls go ahead so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Matrix` class is documented [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html).  A `Matrix` is a templated class allowing standard numeric or user defined types, dynamic or fixed sizing for rows and columns and other options.  The signature is:

> template<typename Scalar_, int Rows_, int Cols_, int Options_, int MaxRows_, int MaxCols_>
> class Eigen::Matrix< Scalar_, Rows_, Cols_, Options_, MaxRows_, MaxCols_ >

The `Scalar_` is the type of the matrix, `float`, `double`, `int`, whatever.
`Rows_` and `Cols_` are the sizes of the matrix.  `Dynamic` is a constant `-1`.  If a positive quantity is not provided at compile time this tells `Eigen` that the matrix is dynamic.  These values are related to `MaxRows_` and `MaxCols_`.
`Options_` is the most complicated one.

> Options_  A combination of either RowMajor or ColMajor, and of either AutoAlign or DontAlign. The former controls storage order, and defaults to column-major. The latter controls alignment, which is required for vectorization. It defaults to aligning matrices except for fixed sizes that aren't a multiple of the packet size.

There is an `enum` in Constants.h that defines some of the values.  Normally `0` is there as most matrices are defaulted to be auto-aligned and column major.  `RowMajor` is `1` and `DontAlign` is `2`.

So to decode your two matrices:
`Matrix<float,4,4,4,4,4>` is a matrix holding `float` values of fixed size 4 x 4 with option of `4`.  Note that `4` is not a valid template parameter so some operation has happened on that matrix which set the options to that value.  This is equivalent to the typedef `Matrix4f` (again with some other operation).

`Matrix<float,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>` is a matrix holding `float` values of dynamic size that is column-major and auto aligned.  This is equivalent to `MatrixXf`.